# Codeigniter drag and drop

Tags: php

I am new to codeigniter.Can anyone please tell me how to include drag and drop feature to upload multiple images in Codeigniter with complete description of MVC Architecture and code.
Here is my controller dropzone.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dropzone extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->helper(array('url','html','form'));
}

public function index() {
$this->load->view('dropzone_view');
}
public function upload() {
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
 $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$targetPath = getcwd() . '/uploads/';
$targetFile = $targetPath . $fileName ;
move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
// if you want to save in db,where here
// with out model just for example
// $this->load->database(); // load database
// $this->db->insert('file_table',array('file_name' => $fileName));
}
   }
}

/* End of file dropzone.js */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/dropzone.php */


 and here is my views:
<html>
<head>
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resouces/css/dropzone.css"         type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resouces/dropzone.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>File Upload using dropzone.js and Codeigniter - arjun.net.in</h1>
<form action="<?php echo site_url('/dropzone/upload'); ?>" class="dropzone"   >
</form>
</body>
</html>

and I also have uploads folder and resources folder that contains copy of  all dropzone-4.0.1 zip file.
But while running localhost/drag/index.php/dropzone , drag is the project     name, it is showing ;

File Upload using dropzone.js and Codeigniter - arjun.net.in
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement via JS into codeigniter.
see this https://github.com/danielm/uploader

Comment: but how to use js as mvc architecture.. in codeigniter .?

Comment: Include all js file into your view and then you can use as per your requirement.

Comment: ok i have included all js files in the view but what about remaining files,like css src etc. and what to write in controller to make the whole code working..?

Comment: which file will I have to run on browser,like what address will I have to give in browser ex:localhost/js/index.php...., after index.php which file will I have to run

Comment: First create one folder on root level. move all your js and css into this folder. call this files into your view using base url like :<?php <hostname>/path/to/folder/filenam ?>.
for calling file please read https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html